# What type of test to use for comparing frequency

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What type of test to use

I’m in college doing a project for my stat class. I have chosen for the project to test my hypothesis that truck sales have increased compared to cars in recent years. For my data, I downloaded an excel sheet that shows number of cars and trucks sold each year from 1990-2020. The problem is I’m supposed to perform a statistics on the data but have no clue what test to perform to compare sales. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: What tests have you learned?

Comment: Z test, regression, anova, and non parametric tests.